# Gitlab does not show Junit report in MR UI for failed job

Tags: xml, junit, gitlab, gitlab-ci, tfsec

I am trying to [view test failures](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/unit_test_reports.html#view-unit-test-reports-on-gitlab) for my GitLab job, but the report is missing.

.gitlab-ci.yaml

```
tfsec:
  stage: validate
  image: aquasec/tfsec-ci:v1.27
  script:
    - cd resources/$MODULE
    - tfsec --version
    - tfsec -f junit -O report.xml .
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/resources/$MODULE/report.xml
    reports:
      junit:  $CI_PROJECT_DIR/resources/$MODULE/report.xml
  allow_failure: true
```

Here is the pipeline output,

```
$ cd resources/$MODULE
$ tfsec --version
v1.27.6
$ tfsec -f junit -O report.xml .
WARNING: A tfvars file was found but not automatically used. Did you mean to specify the --tfvars-file flag?
1 file(s) written: report.xml
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
/<path>/report.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=2621042 responseStatus=201 Created token=_JHdfyHA
Uploading artifacts...
<path>/report.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=2621042 responseStatus=201 Created token=_JHdfyHA
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I get this error in the logs if my job is failed. This is expected because I have tests failed. But what is not expected is that report in my MR for this job is does not show in the MR UI.

What am I missing?

Comment: i used `always` and still have same issue

Comment: So basically I expect the MR to produce me the report of the artifacts, I assume that due to this failure I don't get the report?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. As long as the junit reports are well-formed and your MR was opened before the pipeline ran, I would expect it to show up in the MR UI. If it does not show up there, I'm not sure why that would be the case, but maybe try opening the XML and make sure it matches the Junit test format as expected.